# How to check if interrupts are working or not?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, dma, zynq

I have booted linux into my ZYNQ 7000 (AVNET) board through Jtag, tftpboot. Next, made it boot from QSPI.

The purpose of this project is to transfer data between PS and PL through DMA. I have done the design using VIVADO and used Petalinux to boot linux into the the board. Now I want to write a test code to see if data transfer function is working or not. When I ran my code it hangs "looking for interrupt". Therefore, I want to check if my interrupts are working or not. So I tried  cat/proc/interrupts command in my board terminal and I get 30 to 38 interrupts number as follows (example shown below for 30 only)

30: 0 0 GIC-0 46 level f8003000.dma.controller

My system-user.dtsi file is below:

```
/include/ "system-conf.dtsi"
/ {
    chosen {
            bootargs = "earlycon clk_ignore_unused uio_pdrv_genirq.of_id=generic-uio rootwait quiet loglevel=0";
            stdout-path = "serial0:115200n8";
        };
};

&axi_dma_0 {
        compatible = "generic-uio";
        interrupt-parent = <0x1>;
        interrupts = <0 29 4 0 30 4>;
};

&qspi {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        flash0: flash@0 {
                compatible = "n25q512a","micron,m25p80","jedec,spi-nor";
                spi-max-frequency = <50000000>;
                reg = <0x0>;
                #address-cells = <1>;
                #size-cells = <1>;
        };
};
```

The question is, from the output of the cat /proc/interrupts can I asume that my interrups are working?

EDIT: How can I find the interrupt number that is suppose to be generated when there is data available  for the read command from uio?

Comment: No.  Your device has properly REGISTERED for an interrupt, but you won't know whether they are working or not until you generate one.

Comment: @TimRoberts I assumed if it is registered properly it is working. How to check that?

Comment: You need to do some operations that trigger interrupts, and see if the counts go up.

Comment: @TimRoberts is it possible to do it from cammand line of the board?

Comment: I don't know, it's YOUR hardware.  What IP is doing the DMA?

Comment: @TimRoberts, Sorry, did not understand what you mean by IP. I am very new to this area so finding it very hard to integrate the concepts. I am using uio0 if that is what you aksed. The following video I am tying to implement and test. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ld01yPmW_Xw

Comment: You said you're trying to do DMA.  DMA is when some hardware block controls the data transfer instead of the CPU.  So, what hardware block are you using to do the transfers?

Comment: @TimRoberts, In the Vivado design I used AXI DMA block and AXI data FIFO is this the question?

Comment: OK, then you need to program the registers of the AXI DMA block to do a transfer, and set the "interrupt on complete" bit to request an interrupt.  Remember that you need a physical address for the system memory side.  The UIO driver doesn't provide that, but there's a `udmabuf` driver that can.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you do much for your help. But I could not find udmabuf driver. When I typed ls -/dev/u* in my board command promt I did not see it. When I tried find, I got many returns. May I ask where can I find the udmabuf?

Comment: https://github.com/ikwzm/udmabuf

Comment: The programmed worked when I read from read("/dev/mem", (void*)....) instead of read(fd_uio,(void*).....). So I am assumming interrupts are working. However when I typed   cat /proc/interrupts it still shows 0 for interrupts number 30 to 38. It may be because it was not running when I typed cat /dev/interrupts.

Comment: Well, interrupts are not required for DMA operation.  The transfers will work with or without them.

Comment: @TimRoberts The programme works with reading from /dev/mem but does not work if reading from uio0. What exactly the problem? What code to add so that the programme works reading from  uio0?

Comment: Reading what?  You haven't provided the address in your device tree file, so how could `uio0` know where to find the register space?

Comment: @TimRoberts I have the following in my system-user.dtsi file &axi_dma_0 { compatible = "generic-uio"; interrupt-parent = <0x1>; interrupts = <0 29 4 0 30 4>; }; Is it that I did not add register information? Something like reg = <0x0 0xa0000000 0x0 0x10000> Interestingly I do not have any reg information in pl.dtsi file. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: Yes, that's what you need.  The base address will be in your Verilog output.

Comment: @TimRoberts I added &axi_dma_0 {
    compatible = "generic-uio";
    reg = <0x40400000 0x10000>;
    interrupt-parent = <0x1>;
    interrupts = <0 29 4 0 30 4>;
}; to my system-dtsi file and used the petalinux-build and petalinux-package --boot command but even aafter that all remain same

Comment: And if you go to `/sys/class/uio/uio0/maps/map0`, do `addr` and `size` look right (bearing in mind decimal/hex issues)?

Comment: Yes cat /sys...../addr gives 0x40400000 and cat /sys...../size gives 0x00010000. By the way to make my new system-user.dtsi file work, do I have to power cycle the board and reboot linux? Now my booting is from QSPI.

Comment: @TimRoberts But when I cat /sys....../name I get dma@40400000 not &axi_dma_0 as written in system-user.dtsi file. Is this the problem? What should I write in system-user.dtsi file

Comment: Yes, to change the DeviceTree, you have to copy it into place and reboot.  I don't much care what the name is.  It sounds like you might have another DeviceTree entry for that device.  Have you tried reading the registers through the `uio0` mapping?

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you.  I have never checked what are there under uio, tomorrow I will check, now I don't have acces to the computer,  not sure where the register information I should look.

Comment: You have the Xilinx data sheet that shows the register layout, right?  If you write a program to `mmap` the `uio0` file, as described in the documentation, that's where the register map lives.

Comment: @TimRoberts It seems read from uio works whenever there is data in uio, how this works? In my case it is not reading even when threre is data. I could not find the connection between register and uio interrupt. Any idea what i should read to understand?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "whenever there is data".  The address 0x40400000 SHOULD be the address of the registers for the AXI DMA unit.  You need to write values into those registers to set up a transfer request, and then trigger the transfer.  If you set the "interrupt on complete" bit, then the unit will fire an interrupt when the transfer is complete.  With uio, you do a `read` on the /dev/uio file, and that read blocks until an interrupt happens.

Comment: @TimRoberts , how to find it? I kept looking but not sure how to find.   in here https://docs.xilinx.com/viewer/book-attachment/mxcNFn1EFZjLI1eShoEn5w/pnoMLQXFIWQ6Jhoj0BUsTQ i kept

Comment: Here's the Xilinx AXI DMA guide that includes the register space. https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/pg021_axi_dma/Performance .   Are you working with an experienced hardware engineer?  This stuff is complicated without help.

Comment: @TimRoberts no. I am kind of alone and this is not my background but the situation put me into this. In my case in the vivado design i am using mm2s_introut and s2mm_introut and not scatter/gather mode.

Comment: @TimRoberts The code i am running is exactly the code 
658062_001_DMA_UIO_test.c and it is in the end op the link https://support.xilinx.com/s/question/0D52E00006iHsTLSA0/problem-with-uio-for-axidma?language=en_US

Comment: OK, that code is doing a DMA transfer from the AXI DMA input port into system memory.  What happens when you run that?  Do you actually have a data stream going into the AXI DMA block?  Did you trigger it, where the code says?

Comment: @TimRoberts When I run the code it stops at ##WAITING ON INTERRUPT## it means read never return anything. And my vivado desogn is https://www.fpgadeveloper.com/2014/08/using-the-axi-dma-in-vivado.html/

Comment: That design hooks the input and the output of the DMA unit to a FIFO.  That means you ALSO need a process to FILL the FIFO, otherwise nothing will ever come back.  Do you have that?

Comment: @TimRoberts  where the process to FILL the FIFO should be? Should I have to insert code somewhere in the 658062_001_DMA_UIO_test.c  or I have to do something in the system-user.dtsi?

Comment: It's going to involve changes to the code.  You'll need one MM2S transfer to send from memory into the FIFO, then an S2MM transfer to read back into memory.

Comment: @TimRoberts So I need the FIFO register or location or where do I find that?

Comment: No, the FIFO is not addressable.  It's a standalone unit.  The only way to use it is through the DMA block.  The diagrams show that.  You program the DMA unit for an MM2S transfer to get data INTO the FIFO, then you program the DMA for an S2MM transfer to pull data OUT of the FIFO.  The two directions are mostly separate, so you can actually do both at the same time.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes I can se that M_AXIS_MM2S is conneted to the FIFO. Do you mean after the read (fd_uio,..) I must have block to transfer data from MM2S to FIFO and FIFO to SS2M. In the 658062_001_DMA_UIO_test.c  code there is nothing related to MM2S . Is this the problem?

Comment: @TimRoberts  Do I have to set  the MM2S_DMACR to 0x01015001 and MM2S_Length to mmap. Not sure how? Am I in the right path?

Comment: You need local consulting help.  This is a complicated, interdisciplinary system with many components at multiple levels.  We are NOT going to solve this in a StackOverflow comments stream.

Comment: @TimRoberts I do not have any local support,so I have no options but asking questios here. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I have a ZYNQ(7020) board with  same boot mode. If you want to indentify spi nor flash work status, do as follow:

1. add nor flash support
   kernel have support n25q512a in spi-nor.c,look at https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/mtd/spi-nor/spi-nor.c?h=v4.19.297.  line 1109
2. kernel initalize nor flash(n25q512a)

   When kernel start you will see nor flash initalize log:

> ```
> m25p80 spi0.0: is25wp512 (65536 Kbytes)
> 6 ofpart partitions found on MTD device spi0.0
> Creating 6 MTD partitions on "spi0.0":
> 0x000000000000-0x00000007e000 : "u-boot"
> mtd: partition "u-boot" doesn't end on an erase block -- force read-only
> 0x00000007e000-0x000000080000 : "uboot env"
> mtd: partition "uboot env" doesn't start on an erase block boundary -- force read-only
> 0x000000080000-0x000000a00000 : "boot"
> 0x000000a00000-0x000001a00000 : "rootfs"
> 0x000001a00000-0x000002000000 : "set"
> 0x000002000000-0x000004000000 : "tffs"
> ```

3. read/write data to n25q512a
   Kernel mtd layer will create a nor flash device /dev/mtd0 /dev/mtdblock0
   read from nor flash : **cat /dev/mtd0** or  **flashcp xxxx /dev/mtd0**

write:  your nor flash have only one partition, **don't write/flashcp to /dev/mtd0**, Becasue uboot image is store in postion 0.

after read /dev/mtd0 you will find interrupts  increase, see log:

> ```
> # cat /proc/cpuinfo 
> processor       : 0
> model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 0 (v7l)
> BogoMIPS        : 766.66
> Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpd32 
> CPU implementer : 0x41
> CPU architecture: 7
> CPU variant     : 0x3
> CPU part        : 0xc09
> CPU revision    : 0
>
> processor       : 1
> model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 0 (v7l)
> BogoMIPS        : 766.66
> Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpd32 
> CPU implementer : 0x41
> CPU architecture: 7
> CPU variant     : 0x3
> CPU part        : 0xc09
> CPU revision    : 0
>
> Hardware        : Xilinx Zynq Platform
> Revision        : 0003
> Serial          : 0000000000000000
> # cat /proc/interrupts |grep spi
> 144:     335239          0     GIC-0  51 Level     e000d000.spi
> # cat /proc/interrupts          
>            CPU0       CPU1       
>  16:          0          0     GIC-0  27 Edge      gt
>  17:          0          0     GIC-0  43 Level     ttc_clockevent
>  18:    3515245      42248     GIC-0  29 Edge      twd
>  21:         43          0     GIC-0  39 Level     f8007100.adc
> 141:         21          0     GIC-0  80 Level     cdns-i2c
> 143:        714          0     GIC-0  59 Level     xuartps
> 144:     335239          0     GIC-0  51 Level     e000d000.spi
> 145:        581          0     GIC-0  79 Level     mmc0
> 146:          0          0     GIC-0  45 Level     f8003000.dmac
> 147:          0          0     GIC-0  46 Level     f8003000.dmac
> 148:          0          0     GIC-0  47 Level     f8003000.dmac
> 149:          0          0     GIC-0  48 Level     f8003000.dmac
> 150:          0          0     GIC-0  49 Level     f8003000.dmac
> 151:          0          0     GIC-0  72 Level     f8003000.dmac
> 152:          0          0     GIC-0  73 Level     f8003000.dmac
> 153:          0          0     GIC-0  74 Level     f8003000.dmac
> 154:          0          0     GIC-0  75 Level     f8003000.dmac
> 155:          0          0     GIC-0  40 Level     f8007000.devcfg
> 161:          0          0     GIC-0  41 Edge      f8005000.watchdog
> 162:          2          0     GIC-0  54 Level     eth0
> IPI1:          0          0  Timer broadcast interrupts
> IPI2:     143990     319310  Rescheduling interrupts
> IPI3:         38         72  Function call interrupts
> IPI4:          0          0  CPU stop interrupts
> IPI5:          0          0  IRQ work interrupts
> IPI6:          0          0  completion interrupts
> Err:          0
> # hexdump -C /dev/mtd0 |more 
> 00000000  fe ff ff ea fe ff ff ea  fe ff ff ea fe ff ff ea  |................|
> *
> 00000020  66 55 99 aa 58 4e 4c 58  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |fU..XNLX........|
> 00000030  c0 08 00 00 e0 ba 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
> 00000040  e0 ba 00 00 00 00 00 00  c1 dd 18 fd 00 00 00 00  |................|
> 00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
> *
> 000000a0  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  |................|
> *
> 000008a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
> *
> 000008c0  0f 00 00 ea 14 f0 9f e5  14 f0 9f e5 14 f0 9f e5  |................|
> 000008d0  14 f0 9f e5 14 f0 9f e5  14 f0 9f e5 14 f0 9f e5  |................|
> 000008e0  40 00 00 00 40 00 00 00  40 00 00 00 40 00 00 00  |@...@...@...@...|
> 000008f0  40 00 00 00 40 00 00 00  40 00 00 00 ef be ad de  |@...@...@.......|
> 00000900  fe ff ff ea 12 00 00 ea  00 00 0f e1 1f 10 00 e2  |................|
> 00000910  1a 00 31 e3 1f 00 c0 13  13 00 80 13 c0 00 80 e3  |..1.............|
> 00000920  00 f0 29 e1 10 0f 11 ee  02 0a c0 e3 10 0f 01 ee  |..).............|
> 00000930  84 00 9f e5 10 0f 0c ee  06 00 00 eb 1d 00 00 eb  |................|
> 00000940  86 00 00 eb 15 0f 07 ee  9a 0f 07 ee 95 0f 07 ee  |................|
> 00000950  1e ff 2f e1 eb ff ff ea  00 00 a0 e3 17 0f 08 ee  |../.............|
> 00000960  15 0f 07 ee d5 0f 07 ee  9a 0f 07 ee 95 0f 07 ee  |................|
> 00000970  10 0f 11 ee 02 0a c0 e3  07 00 c0 e3 02 00 80 e3  |................|
> # cat /proc/interrupts
>            CPU0       CPU1       
>  16:          0          0     GIC-0  27 Edge      gt
>  17:          0          0     GIC-0  43 Level     ttc_clockevent
>  18:    3564059      42857     GIC-0  29 Edge      twd
>  21:         43          0     GIC-0  39 Level     f8007100.adc
> 141:         21          0     GIC-0  80 Level     cdns-i2c
> 143:        860          0     GIC-0  59 Level     xuartps
> 144:     335409          0     GIC-0  51 Level     e000d000.spi
> 145:        581          0     GIC-0  79 Level     mmc0
> 146:          0          0     GIC-0  45 Level     f8003000.dmac
> 147:          0          0     GIC-0  46 Level     f8003000.dmac
> 148:          0          0     GIC-0  47 Level     f8003000.dmac
> 149:          0          0     GIC-0  48 Level     f8003000.dmac
> 150:          0          0     GIC-0  49 Level     f8003000.dmac
> 151:          0          0     GIC-0  72 Level     f8003000.dmac
> 152:          0          0     GIC-0  73 Level     f8003000.dmac
> 153:          0          0     GIC-0  74 Level     f8003000.dmac
> 154:          0          0     GIC-0  75 Level     f8003000.dmac
> 155:          0          0     GIC-0  40 Level     f8007000.devcfg
> 161:          0          0     GIC-0  41 Edge      f8005000.watchdog
> 162:          2          0     GIC-0  54 Level     eth0
> IPI1:          0          0  Timer broadcast interrupts
> IPI2:     144133     319683  Rescheduling interrupts
> IPI3:         38         72  Function call interrupts
> IPI4:          0          0  CPU stop interrupts
> IPI5:          0          0  IRQ work interrupts
> IPI6:          0          0  completion interrupts
> Err:          0
> #
> ```

Comment: That's not what he was trying to do.  He's trying to use the AXI DMA module.  This answer is not helpful.